# Dot appeared next to font awesome burger menu

Tags: html, font-awesome

On small screens ( <720px) I have a toggle menu with a font awesome icon.

I noticed yesterday that there is a full stop appearing before the menu. I can't figure out where this is coming from.

**The dot in question.**

[image]

**The code for the menu** (taken from developer tools.)

```
<ul id="toggle-menu">
    <li class="pullDown">
        <a href="#" id="pull">
            <i class="fa fa-bars fa-3x "></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It it appearing in the DOM within this line, even when all elements within the li are deleted.

```
<li class="pullDown"></li>
```

The site is [here](http://purelywebdesign.co.uk)

The full code is [here](https://github.com/tonyedwardspz/Portfolio)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your style.css add this code

```
#toggle-menu li {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aznP5.png) for an example of it in action.

The reason that dot is there is that you're adding it as a list element -- it's not a full stop, necessarily, just the marker for a new element in an unordered list. `list-style-type:none` gets rid of any style for the list elements.

Comment: Spot on, thanks. 
I guess this is a consequence of removing Normalize.css.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a full stop, it's a list item bullet. You're using a list with `<li>` tags, and the default behaviour is to put a bullet in front of whatever is inside the `<li>`

The real answer here though is that your code isn't very semantically correct. Why is an icon inside of an unordered list in the first place? Consider two other options...

1) Just putting `<a>` containing your icon in front of the nav and leaving it at that
2) Incorporating the font awesome icon in to a :before or :after psuedo-element of the nav menu itself using CSS styling. Information about how to add icons via CSS can be found on the font awesome site.

Comment: Good point on semantics. I'll look into changing it to a simple <a>

Answer (score 0):

Your toggle-menu class should contain something like

```
list-style: none;
```